# TypeError: Cannot read property 'CheckOnce' of undefined

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

I'm trying to run an angular2-meteor app, but, when I open it on the browser, I get an error:

> constants.js:66Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CheckOnce' of
>   undefined

can anyone help me?

Comment: Just don't call `CheckOnce` on `undefined`. That's the best advice to such a question.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It would be nice to edit your question and add the code you've written so far : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I met same error.

Like @barbatus said [here](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap/issues/20), location of `CheckOnce` might have changed.

`CheckOnce` is from Angular2's `ChangeDetectionStrategy`.
So I solve it by updating from

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
```

to

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```